# Using IDbConnection and how to convert String to Clob

Tags: c#

I am try to convert a string to Clob in C#. But the connection I use the IDbConnection.

It is doesn't work it. The OracleClob only can use the OracleConnection, it can not use in IDbConnection.

```
using (IDbConnection db = new OraCon().CONN())

byte[] newvalue = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(htmlinvoice);
var clob = new OracleClob(db);
clob.Write(newvalue, 0, newvalue.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that is the case, yes. Not sure what exactly new OraCon().CONN() returns , but if it's an OracleConnection, you could maybe convert it explicitly in the CLOB constructor:

```
using (IDbConnection db = new OraCon().CONN())
{
    byte[] newvalue = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(htmlinvoice);
    var clob = new OracleClob((OracleConnection)db);
    clob.Write(newvalue, 0, newvalue.Length);
}
```

If it's not an OracleConnection, but some other IDbConnection, it won't work indeed, as the documentation specifies it needs an OracleConnection (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleClobClass.htm#ODPNT4093).

You're also missing the curly braces in the code you pasted.

DISCLAIMER: cannot try this code right now, but feels like it should work.

Comment: Thank for Answer. I know OracleClob only can use on OracleConnection. But I am using the IDbConnection. Do you know how to use IDbConnection and convert String to Clob?
Thanks.